# how do i sequence methods in libgdx

Tags: timer, libgdx, sequencing

I am using libgdx and i have several game objects with different methods i want the methods in my timer to happen one after another but in libgdx they happen all at once i dont know how to fix it

```
    timer.scheduleTask( task = new Task(){ public void run(){
    rando =rn.nextInt(8);
    Gdx.app.log("the num is", Integer.toString(rando));
    if(rando == 0){
        bush.rustle();
        bush2.rustle2();
        bush3.dontrustle3();
        bush4.dontrustle4();
        enemy.shoot();
        enemy2.shoot();
        enemy3.godown();
        enemy4.godown();


    }
     if(rando == 1){
        bush.dontrustle();
        bush2.rustle2();
        bush3.rustle3();
        bush4.dontrustle4();
        enemy.godown();
        enemy2.shoot();
        enemy3.shoot();
        enemy4.godown();

    }
    if(rando == 2){
        bush.rustle();
        bush2.dontrustle2();
        bush3.rustle3();
        bush4.rustle4();
        enemy2.godown();
        enemy.shoot();
        enemy4.shoot();
        enemy3.shoot();


    }

    if(rando == 3){
        bush.rustle();
        bush2.rustle2();
        bush3.rustle3();
        bush4.rustle4();
        enemy.shoot();
        enemy2.goup();
        enemy4.goup();
        enemy3.shoot();

    }

    if(rando == 4){
        bush.rustle();
        bush2.rustle2();
        bush3.rustle3();
        bush4.rustle4();
        enemy2.godown();
        enemy.godown();
        enemy4.shoot();
        enemy3.shoot();


    }
```

how it works is that everytime a number is called a set of methods run but they run all at once i want them to run one after the other

Comment: The method themself *do* run one after another. Your problem probably is that the *effects* the methods creates happen all at once. I suggest using some event queue to store upcoming tasks to do, once a task is complete, next from the queue can start.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the libgdx-ai extension.  It has some utilities for building up and reacting to events.  The [state machine](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-ai/wiki/State-Machine) is probably overkill for what you want, but might have ideas you can crib from.

See also https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14568/integrating-an-ai-state-machine-with-actions-that-take-more-than-1-tick

A lighter-weight approach might be something like this: http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/06/java-secret-using-enum-as-state-machine.html (though I recommend doing this mostly as a way to understand the more complex AI library state machine).